Bond prices between coupon dates
So, I'm new in this subject. Recently introduced to bond prices and my teacher is not so good. Can you help me check the steps for solving the problem? I include some of my doubts.
Find the clean and dirty price of a bond that pays coupons every 4 months. The bond started on April 15, 2017, and the valuation date is July 15, 2022. The bond has a $12.5\%$ interest rate, a face value of $\$500$, and is expected to be redeemed at $\$580$ with a $12\%$ interest rate. Calculate for $r=8\%$ trimestral at January 18, 2023.
DATA:
(face value) $F=500$
(redemption value) $N=580$
(interest rate (based on the coupon payment period)) $i=12.5\%/4$
(coupon rate per coupon payment period) $r=8\%/4$
(Coupon Value) $C=Fr=500(8\%/4)$
(Total of coupons to pay) $n_c=16$
First, we seek the value of the bond on April 15, 2017:
Using $P=Fra_{ni}+Nv^n$ we get $P=500\cdot \frac{8\%}{4}\cdot \frac{1-(1+12.5\%/4)^{-4}}{12.5\%/4}+508(1+12.5\%/4)^{-4}=486.23$
Now, for the dirty price ($P_s$):
$P_s=(P_m+C)(1+r)^{-T}$, where $T=(n-m)/360$ and $P_m=500\cdot \frac{8\%}{4}\cdot\frac{1-(1+12.5\%/3)^{-T}}{12.5\%/3}+508(1+12.5\%/3)^{-T}$. (With this, I have a doubt. The part $508(1+12.5\%/3)^{-T}$ should be $n_c(1+12.5\%/3)^{-T}$???)
So, $n$ refers the days between April 15, 2017 and July 15, 2022 ($n=1917$); $m$ refers the days between April 15, 2017 and January 18, 2023 ($m=2104$). With respect to a 360 days year, we get
$$T=\frac{m-n}{360}=\frac{\frac{2104}{360}-\frac{1917}{360}}{360}=\frac{187}{129600}$$
After that, we substitute in $P_t=P_s-CT$ (for the clean price), but this expression is correct? I was told that it is the redemption value $N$ instead of coupon value $C$.
In advanced, thanks for your help.
